# How to organize coffescript in better way

Tags: javascript, coffeescript

I have the following coffescript code:

```
  hideOther = -> 
   $('[class^=addition_translation]').hide()

  $('.en_addition').click ->
    hideOther()  
    $('.addition_translation_en').show()

  $('.pl_addition').click ->
    hideOther()  
    $('.addition_translation_pl').show()

  $('.de_addition').click ->
    hideOther()  
    $('.addition_translation_de').show()

  $('.fr_addition').click ->
    hideOther()  
    $('.addition_translation_fr').show()

  $('.it_addition').click ->
    hideOther()  
    $('.addition_translation_it').show()

  $('.ua_addition').click ->
    hideOther()  
    $('.addition_translation_ua').show() 

  $('.ru_addition').click ->
    hideOther()  
    $('.addition_translation_ru').show()
```

Which way will be the best to write this code without this unnecessary repetitions?

Edit:

```
  countries = ["pl", "en"]
     for country in countries
       $(".#{country}_addition").click ->
        hideOther()  
        $(".addition_translation_#{country}").show()
```

I do it in this way, maybe is better way to do it?

Comment: `$("[class*=_addition]").click -> $("[class*=addition_translation]").hide() && $(".addition_translation_"+this.className.split("_")[0]).show()` but it's quite horrible really. This logic should not be managed in class names at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With corrected indentation (since indentation matters in CoffeeScript), that should be just fine:

```
countries = ["pl", "en"]
for country in countries
  $(".#{country}_addition").click ->
    hideOther()  
    $(".addition_translation_#{country}").show()
```

It does set a separate function on each of the `.XX_addition` elements, but unless there are thousands of them or they are dynamically added, that should be fine.

Your other option is event delegation, having *one* function that handles all of these elements. This is (again) particularly handy when the list is dynamic.

Assuming all of these `.addition_translation_XX` elements are in some container (I'll call it `.container`):

```
$(".container").on "click", "[class$=_addition]", ->
  country = this.className.substring 0, 2
  $("[class^=addition_translation]").hide()
  $(".addition_translation_#{country}").show()
```

There we're saying: Hook the click on the container, but only call our handler if it passes through an element matching `"[class$=_addition]"` (an element whose class attribute *ends with* `_addition`). jQuery will call our handler with `this` referring to that element, so we get the country from the `className`, hide the other countries, and show that one.

Note that like your `"[class^=addition_translation]"` selector assumes that the `XX_addition_translation` class is the only (or at least last) class in those elements' class lists, the above assumes that `XX_addition` is the only (or at least first) class in *those* elements' class lists. In both cases, I wouldn't make that assumption, it's fragile; instead, I'd use a class to mark the elements *without* the country information (so just `.addition` and `.addition_translation` and then add a `data-country` attribute to them:

```
<span class="addition" data-country="ru">...</span>
<div class="addition_translation" data-country="ru">...</div>
```

Then:

```
$(".container").on "click", ".addition", ->
  country = this.getAttribute "data-country"
  $(".addition_translation").hide()
  $(".addition_translation[data-country=#{country}]").show()
```

Comment: @SylvainLeroux: [You're right](http://coffeescript.org/#loops), thanks! I'll fix that.